# How to query from multiple tables of date range in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have oracle tables like below `schema.ITEM_DATA_2017_01_01, schema.ITEM_2017_01_02, schema.ITEM_DATA_201_01_03` .... like that with same column names. Actually these are the history table which will create when running a job.
How do i perform a search across all the tables given a date range using sql developer.
Please help.

Regards, 
Ramesh

Comment: Why are you creating tables like this? Modify the job to use one history table and add a date column to it that can include when the items were added then you bypass the issue.

Comment: Is it really a requirement to do this using SQL Developer specifically? I use PL/SQL Developer, so sounds like I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the good old union, but I believe you are looking for something like this, which as far as I know is not supported in Oracle: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#table-date-range

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, any help on the union part  ?

Comment: We don't know the columns you are interested, but it is basically:
select * from ITEM_DATA_2017_01_01 union all select * from ITEM_DATA_2017_01_02 etc. (use union instead of union all if data can be duplicated across tables)

Answer (score 0):

It is not good design and it's quite strange to do such set of table only for complication of searching against them.

If you sure you really need this strange approach, you can use `UNION ALL` to make this table together. Maybe you should create a union-ed view and modify it in the your job which creates tables, maybe you should build this statement on the fly using given data range. But in most cases better way is to drop bad idea and use just one table, optionally partitioned.